# Subsetting a list of multidimensional arrays

Tags: arrays, r, lapply

I am trying to subset a list of 3d arrays, to return a list of matrices. I assume the answer involves lapply, but all of the previous questions I find are complicated by other issues.

toy example:

```
x <- array(1:300, dim=c(20, 5, 3))
y <- array(301:600, dim=c(20, 5, 3))

list <- list(x ,y)
```

I want the [,,1] elements from both arrays, in a new list of matrices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For future reference - try not to overwrite built-in functions such as `list` in global environment.

To answer your questions:

```
lapply(list(x,y), function(m) m[,,1])
```

`lapply` will iterate over all elements in the list, passing each as an argument to the function you provide.

Comment: `lapply(list(x,y), '[', ,,1)` is the same